# Instantiation within a conditional statement

Tags: java, instantiation

I'm exploring the idea of one-time instantiation as a possible different approach to secure object handling. The idea is to instantiate, test, and dispose of an object completely within the condition of an `if` statement, but I'm having some trouble instantiating the object to begin with. I think the problem lies with how I'm approaching the concept, but I'm eager to see if there's perhaps a way I can reorganise the condition.

```
if((new ResultSet(dbPwdTest.getResultSet())).getString(1).equals(pwd/*need to hash this*/))
                {
                    return true;
                }
```

Is this at all possible? Currently, the compiler returns "cannot instantiate the type 'ResultSet'".

Edit: Perhaps the answer lies in using the ResultSet contained within the PreparedStatement, so the following would work:

```
if(dbPwdTest.getResultSet().getString(1).equals(pwd/*hash! hash! hash!*/))
                {
                    return true;
                }
```

Although I'm not sure that this approach is really the same.

Comment: Yes, it's entirely possible, just not with `ResultSet`. Why are you trying to create an instance of an interface?

Comment: `ResultSet` is an interface, so you can't create an instance of it (unless you supply an implementation).

Comment: In what way do you think this makes your code "secure"? `java.sql.ResultSet` is an interface so you can't instantiate it like this.

Comment: And don't you *already* have a `ResultSet` from `dbPwdTest.getResultSet`? If not, I'd seriously suggest renaming that method... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The idea is to contain the entire test condition (i.e. no instantiation outside of the condition) without allowing any more than one external test item. However, instantiating an instance of ResultSet would be a bit heavier, which is why I was hoping that this wouldn't be necessary.

Additionally, getResultSet is a method of PreparedStatement - although I have an idea which I will post below.

Comment: @Wolfish If `dbPwdTest.getResultSet()` already returns a `ResultSet`object, why are you trying to create another one from it?

Comment: @Jesper The idea is to immediately dispose of all test objects when the if statement is complete, and the thought behind this is more about web implementation.

Comment: @BackSlash Please see my edit

Comment: @Wolfish I saw your edit, but still cannot understand what is the reason behind that choice. If you need to dispose the object as soon as you use it, why don't you use a try-finally or a try-with-resources?

Comment: @BackSlash Try-with-resources is a new one to me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

To instantiate an interface you need to create an implementation of it. This can be done but it would make the condition very hard to read. I would suggest instantiating the interface right before the if-statement. But to answer your question:

```
if((new ResultSet(dbPwdTest.getResultSet()) {
            //implement the interface methods
        }).getString(1).equals(pwd/*need to hash this*/))
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach. Using this method, it may even be possible to contain the entire database query within the condition, making the whole method *really* disposable.